# Is it possible to limit the search of Google Map autocomplete to borough

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have been looking at this documentation of Google Map API.It restricts the user search to a country.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=sv-SE#ComponentRestrictions

Now, Is it possible to limit the search of Google Map to specific region(borough) of a particular city.I was looking for a demo example to limit my search to specific borough of New York City.E.g if the user has selected Manhattan, then the search should display addresses related to Manhattan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can!

In the V3 Google maps API, look for 'locality'. It is under 'component filtering'.

Here is is the link.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding#ComponentFiltering

You can see the functional example on Google maps by typing in 'Queens, NY' in Google maps search. The light boundary outline on the map is what you are after.

[You can see the light pink outline of Queens in this map link.](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?gl=US&ie=UTF8&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=208663737572058601587.0004832d473bc4c51e68f&dg=feature)